# How to convert conditional constraint to concert C++ for cplex?

Tags: c++, linear-programming, cplex

i wrote a model with IBM ILOG Cplex optimization Studio using OPL for Linear Programming. But now i need to write same model using concert c++. But i can not convert my constraints.

One of my constraints is as below:

```
forall(i in Nodes)
           edgeSum[i]:                
              if(i==0)
                sum (j in Ein[0])x[<j,i>] - sum (j in Eout[0])x[<i,j>] == -1;
              else if (i>=1 && i<n/2)
                sum (j in Ein[i])x[<j,i>] - sum (j in Eout[i])x[<i,j>] == 0;     
             else 
               sum (j in Ein[i])x[<j,i>] <= 1;
```

Especially i need to know how to write conditional constraints. 
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
for (i=0; i<numNodes; i++)
{
  if (i == 0)
  {
    IloExpr expr1(env);
    for (j=0; j<numIn[0]; j++)
      expr1 += x[EInIndex[0][j]];
    IloExpr expr2(env);
      expr2 += x[EOutIndex[0][j]];
    model.add(expr1 - expr2 == -1);
  }
  else if ((i >= 1) && (i < n/2))
  {
    // etc
  }
  else
  {
   // etc
  }
}
```

I just did this from memory, so the syntax is probably mangled a bit, and I haven't filled in all the details of all the cases - they should be do-able with a similar structure. I have also probably mangled your indices - not sure how you are remodelling your slicing approach in your C++ code, so I guessed a bit based on what I have done before. Also I didn't name the constraint - that can easily be added too. Look at some of the C++ examples provided with CPLEX.

Hope this helps a bit

Comment: Thanks for your answer
İ also have one more constraint as:
forall(<i,j> in Cedges : i!=0)
           connectivity[<i,j>]:
            (x[<i,j>]==1 ) =>  sum(j in Parents[i])x[<j,i>]==1;

I rewrote this as:

for(int i=1; i< (edgesize*2)+1; i++)
 { 
  if(parents[Cedges[(i)][0]]!=0 && Cedges[(i)][0]!=0)
  {
   model.add( IloIfThen(env, ( x[Indexes[Cedges[i][0]][Cedges[i][1]]] == 1 ),( x[Indexes[parents[Cedges[i][0]]][Cedges[i][0]]] == 1)));
  }
 }
I need to know whether this usage is correct or not.

Comment: Don't have time to check right now, but things you can do to check are:

Comment: Don't have time to check right now, but things you can do to check are to start with a simple problem instance that is small enough to understand and:
(1) output the model as an LP file or similar and check that it makes sense (i.e. the constraints have the right variables in them, with sensible coeffs)
(2) If you know what the answer should be in small cases, check it
(3) given a problem that you know well, try adding extra constraints that would deliberately break the model. So if you know that a value should be zero in your answer, try adding a constraint to force it to be 1.